# How to prevent some event not to propagate - JQuery

Tags: jquery, click

I want to show a pop-up when a variable '$myvar' has the value 'myvalue', so I put this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            if($myvar=='my value'){
            $("#overlay").removeClass("invisible");
            $("#message").removeClass("invisible");
            }
        $('#message #close').live('click',function() {
            $("#overlay").addClass("invisible");
            $("#message").addClass("invisible");
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is related to

```
<div id="overlay" class="invisible"></div>
        <div class="invisible" id="message">
    <div class="header">
        <h2><span><?php echo _('some message!') ?></span>    </h2>
        <div id="close"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So when the user comes to this page and when the variable is set to 'myvalue', the pop-up appears, but I can't close it when I cleick on the #close tag. Is the event 'click' bubbling so that the script is processed again ? If yes, how to prevent it ?

Comment: No. The document.ready event will only trigger once when the page loads.

Comment: Based on the HTML you posted, it looks like there is no `#follow_message`, and even if there were it wouldn't be necessary. Try with just `$('#close')`.

Comment: Are you sure about this selector: $('#follow_message #close') ??? You should use this instead: $('#close')

Comment: BTW live is depreciated, use delegation with .on()

Comment: @Juhana Sorry, I updated my post, it is indeed #message, but this is still not working

Comment: Then there's something you're not showing us. The code in the question works, as Richard's answer shows. Please put the page online somewhere or use jsfiddle to make a version that shows the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me, the only issue is that your html doesn't have a wrapping element with `id="follow_message"` as your JS seems to expect. I assume that you've just missed a bit from your question though.

Fixing that it seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/vcQrV/

**Edit:** So having fixed your JS to use `#message` it's still working: http://jsfiddle.net/vcQrV/1/

Comment: Sorry, I updated my post, it is indeed #message, but this is still working

Comment: no in fact, I still have a weird behavior. When I close the pop-up, the pop-up appears again

Comment: As @Juhana says, there must be something you're not telling us. Can you make a jsFiddle that reproduces the issue?

Answer (score -1):

Here:

```
$('#close').die('click');
$('#close').live('click',function() {
});
```

`live()`, however, is deprecated. Use `on()` instead.

Cheers!